# Random Walk (Combinatorics: number of ways to reach end of the straight line)

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

This is similar to flight of staircase problem, but can't be solved with Fibonacci sequence. Therefore I am trying to a **derive the formula**.

Problem:
Grasshopper begins his journey from cell 0 and can jump a distance of 1 to J cells. Jumping is possible only on an integer number of cells and only forward. Count the number of ways that a grasshopper can get on the cell F(finish).

Example:
J (jump) = 2
F (finish) = 3
Result = 3 (0->1->2->3, 0->1->3, 0->2->3)

<strike>I've calculated sequences for J = 4 & and J = 5 like this:

sum of elements in (sequence from 0 to J) + (sequence from J to F).
But it feels clumsy. Moreover I don't understand the complete logic behind this, this was just a brute-force solution.

Although I've noticed that:

sequence from 0 to J is a sequence of power of 2 (from 0 to N)

sequence from J to F is a Fibonacci-like sequence F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) ... + F(n-n) - ???</strike>

J = 4, F = 1, Res = 1,
J = 4, F = 2, Res = 2
J = 4, F = 3, Res = 4
J = 4, F = 4, Res = 8
J = 4, F = 5, Res = 16
J = 4, F = 6, Res = 31
J = 4, F = 7, Res = 61
J = 4, F = 8, Res = 120

J = 5, F = 1, Res = 1
J = 5, F = 2, Res = 2
J = 5, F = 3, Res = 4
J = 5, F = 4, Res = 8
J = 5, F = 5, Res = 15
J = 5, F = 6, Res = 29
J = 5, F = 7, Res = 56
J = 5, F = 8, Res = 108

Please help to derive a formula. I know that this is a combinatoric problem. Also feel free to point out where I can read about most common combinatoric problems with explanation of how to approach them.

## Solution

**UPD:** scratch all that. The problem is simple as is a solution.
Basically it goes like: *in how many ways you can combine numbers of {1...Jump} to get a [Finish].*
This is a composition:

> A composition of an integer n is a way of writing n as the sum of a
> sequence of (strictly) positive integers.

*And the answer can be calculated as Fibonacci numbers of higher order. For example if Jump is 4 it's Tetranacci, 7 - Heptanacci and so on. You only need to get the n-th number of the sequence.*

Comment: The last move most be one of $1,\cdots, J$.  Hence the recursion is $A_n=A_{n-1}+\cdots A_{n-J}$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html discusses the family of sequences generated (under an offset), but I'm not sure whether any of the formulae given there will be useful to you.

Comment: This is not a random walk at the first place. I've figured out the solution and updated the first post.